# Receive message from socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to receive a message from an RFID reader in my port 8081:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];               
System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.150.111");
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, 8081); 
Socket sListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
sListener.Connect(remoteEP);
```

When I step into code using a breakboint in `Connect` method I see this:

```
'sListener.EnableBroadcast' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException':
"An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call"
```

Any idea what this may mean?

Comment: Why don't you use a `TcpClient`? You're not showing the entire code as well, as you don't set `EnableBroadcast` anywhere in the code above...

Comment: are you sure it support TCP???? UDP is common protocol for RFID Reader ??

Comment: Who is setting EnableBroadcast to *true*??  It is only supported for UDP, not TCP.  Clearly you should have posted the stack trace of the exception, that shows how it got to EnableBroadcast.  Note that the name "sListener" is incredibly misleading, a listener should always call Accept(), not Connect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is why I love SO....

combining Thorsten and Pelletiers comment I managed to solve my issue...

Indeed I need to set a `UDP` connection.

So I made a `UDP CLient`.

Thank you both..